# need some beginner guide about classes

Tags: java, class

I just started learning Java and I have a problem with defining a class.
I defined some variables in a class, but everywhere I wrote a command for printing a value of a string (or other variables) I got an error that says "cannot find symbol". Does that mean I can't use a print command in a class? Can you do a favor and simply explain me what to do?

Here is my codes (it's just for testing):

```
class Variable {
    int m = 15;
    boolean myb = true;
    double mon = 2.4;
}
```

Comment: This code doesnt have print. Show us how you try to print

Comment: sorry, System.out.println (m);

Comment: are you trying to type `Variable.m` , `Variable.myb` or `Variable.mon`? If yes, then problem is in fact, that you wrote an class and you should manipulate an object of that class
`Variable obj=new Variable();` and then use `System.out.println(obj.m)`

Comment: You can declare variables at the top-level of a class, but you can't execute statements like println - these need to go in initialisers, constructors or methods.

Answer (score 1):

if you have

```
class Variable {
    public int m = 15;
    public boolean myb = true;
    public double mon = 2.4;
}
```

iv'e added public modifier so fields are accessible 
then your print code should be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Variable object=new Vairable(); //create instance of class
            System.out.println(object.m);
            System.out.println(object.myb);
            System.out.println(object.mon);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to print from a method within the class, not just in the class.

```
class Variable {
    int m = 15;
    boolean myb = true;
    double mon = 2.4;

    public void printVars() {
        System.out.println("m: " + m);
        System.out.println("myb: " + myb);
        System.out.println("mon: " + mon);
    }
}
```

After that, you would create a new `Variable` and call it's `printVars()` method.

Or, if this class is what you're trying to run, you could put your main in here.

```
class Variable {
    static int m = 15;
    static boolean myb = true;
    static double mon = 2.4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("m: " + m);
        System.out.println("myb: " + myb);
        System.out.println("mon: " + mon);
    }
}
```

Comment: second code cant be executed, because of trying to acces non static object form static context